# Can we use Idea's on Napili template in Salesforce Communities?

Tags: community, ideas

I want to expose Idea's in Communities using Napili template. I dont see this object being exposed there. Any idea if this is even possible or not ? Any workaround of doing it if it is not possible ?

Answer (score 1):

yes. you can. there is free component on AppExchange
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000E9l50UAB

Answer (score 0):

Idea's is currently not supported in Napili template .Please [check](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DtvIAAS) this idea and upvote .

There is a workaround .As Napili is built on lightning component framework you can build your own lightning component on Top of standard SFDC Idea Object .

If you have access to lightning DEVS you can build your own lightning component or wait for a component on appexchange .